# Affect iFrame CSS from within content in SharePoint Online

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, sharepoint

I'm generating a modal form with the following standard code:

```
function openMyForm() { 
  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ 
    url: currentSite + "/SiteAssets/myForm.aspx" 
    title: "My Form", 
    allowMaximize: false, 
    showClose: true, 
    width: 1000,  
    height: 600
  }); 
}
```

There's a problem with the CSS however - the close button position is off:
[image]

The issue can be traced to the following CSS:

```
.ms-dlgTitleBtns {
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-right: -18px;
  height: 30px;
  float: right;
}
```

Specifically margin-right should be 0px.

myForm.aspx is in an iFrame generated by SharePoint, which includes the above CSS. How can I change that value or otherwise get that close button in the right place. I.e.:

[image]

I've tried adding

```
.ms-dlgTitleBtns {
  margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

and

```
$(function() {  

    $(".ms-dlgTitleBtns").css("margin-right","0");

});
```

to myForm.aspx but of course there's no effect due to the iFrame.

Comment: Are you able to add content to the page from which the dialog box is being opened (as opposed to only on the form)?

Comment: Yes I'm able to edit the content of the page from which the dialog box is being opened. I have not tried editing that content from the modal dialog form if that's what you mean...

Comment: Have you tried embedding your CSS there instead of on the form?

Comment: Just tried it. Not sure exactly where to but it tried $(".ms-dlgTitleBtns").css("margin-right","0"); and $("#dlgTitleBtns").css("margin-right","0"); after the SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog call and in the callback. No effect seen.

Comment: @Thriggle I got this to work, after properly refreshing my app.js file - thank you!!

Comment: Great! I'll go ahead and add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic element with the class `ms-dlgTitleBtns` is located on the hosting page, rather than on the form itself; putting your custom script/CSS on the same page saves you from having to modify content on a different page through an iframe.

You can add your JavaScript/CSS to the page from which the dialog box is being opened instead of adding it to the form itself.

(Just make sure you properly refresh your app.js file after implementing the change.)

Answer (score 1):

If the iframe is served from the same site as the outer page, you can access it with:

```
  $('#iframeId').contents()
```

Comment: It is in the same site, but doesn't seem to have an Id: <iframe frameborder="0" style="border: none; position: absolute; z-index: 1504; width: 1042px; height: 480px; left: 280px; top: 10px;"></iframe>

Comment: I tried:
 $('iframe').contents().find('.ms-dlgTitleBtns').css('margin-right','0px'); 

with no result

Comment: Debug it in the console -- which part isn't working?  For example, does `$('iframe').contents()` have a value?

Comment: $('iframe').contents() returns: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: It looks like the iframe is either (1) not the one you want (is there more than one) or (2) not served from the same server as your page.  I assume you changed it to example.com -- in the real error, does the URL in the browser match the URL in the iframe?

Comment: Yes there appears to be more than one iframe and the URL is the parent site, not the URL of the form I'm opening modal. I'll try to post the entire html

Comment: I'm not able to post the entire html cause SharePoint adds too much junk for me to scrub (even in jsfiddle), but I found that: $('iframe:eq(0)').contents() and $('iframe:eq(1)').contents() return objects

Comment: $('iframe:eq(0)').contents() appears to the be the iframe I want, but $('iframe:eq(0)').contents().find('#dlgTitleBtns').css('margin-right','0px'); still does nothing

Comment: debug it -- does the find('#dlgTitleBtns') return anything?

Comment: $('iframe:eq(1)').contents().find('#dlgTitleBtns') returns an empty object

Comment: The HTML is: <iframe frameborder="0" style="border: none; position: absolute; z-index: 1504; width: 1042px; height: 517px; left: 280px; top: 10px;"></iframe><div class="ms-dlgContent" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialogTitleSpan" tabindex="-1" style="z-index: 1505; display: block; width: 1040px; height: 515px; left: 280px; top: 10px;"><div class="ms-dlgBorder" style="width: 1038px; height: 513px;">...

Comment: So the div sits on top of the iframe not in it? I'm not too familiar with iframes... But if that is the case I should be able to access the div CSS with something as simple as $(".ms-dlgTitleBtns").css("margin-right","0");

Answer (score 1):

Thriggle is correct, the dialog framing comes from the hosting sharepoint page, not your form. You can tweak the styling using a script editor on the host page.